# MiKTeX/TeXworks/Windows 10 multiple pdfTeX processes maxing out CPU

Tags: pdftex, miktex, texworks, miktex2.9

I'm new in all these latex stuff and also in this group. So far, I've been able to solve my problems by myself, but this one really got me. I was writing an article, when I realized that texworks began to compile very very slowly. Then, looked at the task manager and saw what you can see now in this image:

[image]

Ok, I wasn't expecting that texworks could work with just one process, but 5? I had to close everything and end up the processes manually because even when closing texworks the processes were still there. Later, tried to continue with my work, but after a few compilations happened all over again. Before killing all the processes and taking that screenshot, there were more than 5. Could someone explain what's going on? Any solution? Thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Does your document compile without error? Which compilation method are you using (what is beside the green arrow)? Do you see the console output during the compilation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX. And yes, my code was compiling with error. I was trying to type a "<" symbol in math mode when the error appeared, but the console showed problems with bibtex. When I took out the "<" symbol the code compiled without error and there's where I think the problem began because I compiled the code several times trying to fix it. Finally, I realized that the root of the problem was the conflict between the `babel` and `breqn` packages. Removing the `breqn` package solved the problem of not being able to compile the "<" in math mode and never had the CPU problem again.